# Where can I find advanced jQuery/JavaScript resources/tutorials?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm reading some tutorials now about jQuery.. function creating,plugin creation etc. but these tutorials are missing some basic explanations like they mention things like

function prototype, anonymous functions, umm putting (jQuery) after the }); .. and stuff like that .. is there a tutorial/website/book that explain these I'm not sure how to call them "terms" from beginner level to advance. I'm mean I have a knowledge of some jquery syntax but not enough to understand this, can anyone recommend useful resource?

Google doesn't help much, I googled "advance features of jquery" don't really get me the things I wanna know.

**EDIT**

Also if someone can share his/her <strike>story</strike> steps on how to become comfortable with javascript, how to overcome this "terminology" or whatever is called

Comment: @Mark Byers sure I do, which ones?

Comment: @c0mrade: There's no need to ask whether or not to make it CW.  You can chose to do it if you feel it is more a community discussion, or it will be done for you.  My recommendation is that yes, this should be a CW post.

Comment: @casperOne alright then it is CW

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722038/advance-javascript-book-recommendation

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen then this seems duplicate question.. delete?

Comment: It may be closed.  I don't think you have to delete it.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen it got voted up two times, some people may want to know some more resources.. I'll just leave it for now ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For JavaScript, there is: [Javascript The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742)

For jQuery, I'd suggest: [The jQuery CookBook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596159788)

I'd also suggest some podcasts and screencasts:

[yayQuery](http://yayquery.com/)

[jQuery for Designers](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/)

Answer (score 2):

John Resig (creator of jQuery) has a small website/tutorial on this very subject of Advanced Javascript.
It's quite enlightening:

http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/

It's basically excerpts from his upcoming book, [Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja](http://jsninja.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you could have some gaps that could quickly be address by reading about the fundamentals, e.g [Wikipedia Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript).

Whilst what you are doing may seem advanced, you may get better results searching for Javascript Tutorial without the advanced keyword. Advanced Javascript is a lot more complicated than what you're doing. I'd even be so bold as to suggest that it is more basic Javascript knowledge that would help if improved.

Comment: @Richard Harrison I went trough this already, but obviously I need to do it again.. I'm on it

Answer (score 0):

Search for jquery on http://net.tutsplus.com and google visual jquery. They have some beginner tutorials.

Comment: @Catfish I'm a plus user already, seeing most tutorials, but none explain things like what does it mean prototype based, first-class, anonymous function .. etc .. I'm looking at how to make socialize plugin with jqeury by Karl S, he just assumess that you know these things, its not bad tutorial .. maybe I missed basics, can you recommend few of them ?